# Error from installing Django using pip on mac

Tags: python, django

Hello I'm getting this error on my mac when i tried installing Django using pip. I created a directory and virtual environment. But ran into this error when attempting to install django.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 731, in install
**kwargs
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 841, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1040, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 343, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 314, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.0.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 82, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django'
```

Comment: You haven't activated your virtualemv.

Comment: @DanielRosemanThanks that was the problem. Im new to python and Django and learning the concepts. Thanks a lot

Comment: The basic intro to virtual environments: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 2):

Have you activated your virtual environment?

`source env/bin/activate`

It looks like you are running the default pip and you don't have permission to install into the directory. If you run `sudo pip install django` it should work.

Comment: yes that was the error not activating my virtual environment. Thanks